# CountD of employees who were active only during date range specified?

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a workbook where I am trying to countD a 1 or a 0 when a workers hire/term (if they termed) date fall within a start/end date parameter range.

I filtered to an employee who was hired on 6/1/21 and didn't terminate. Based on the date parameters on the right, it should be a 0 counted, but it's a 1? The date range is 2020, so the employee wasn't hired yet.

[image]

```
COUNTD(
IF 
    Year([Hire Date])>=Year([Start Date]) and ISNULL([Termination Date (Blank for Currently Active)])
    OR  [Hire Date]<[Start Date] and ISNULL([Termination Date (Blank for Currently Active)])
    OR [Hire Date]>=[Start Date] and [Termination Date (Blank for Currently Active)]<=[End Date]
THEN
    [Employee ID]
END
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using OR evaluators, this will always return as ***True*** and give an Employee ID whether the `[Hire Date]` is greater or less than the `[Start Date]`.

Since we are just checking hire date, we do not need *Termination Date* to compare against. I'd rewrite this to look something like:

```
IF [Hire Date]>= [Start Date] AND [Hire Date]<= [End Date]
THEN [Employee ID]
END
```

This checks if the `[Hire Date]` is in your date range, if it is, it returns `[Employee ID]`, if it isn't, it does nothing. Take the COUNTD of this and you should be good to go.

You could also use the same logic to return a 1 or 0 and then just take the SUM of this calculated field. It works almost the same:

```
IF [Hire Date]>= [Start Date] AND [Hire Date]<= [End Date]
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

Or equivalently and even shorter

```
INT([Hire Date]>= [Start Date] AND [Hire Date]<= [End Date])
```